# Jquery blur doesn't work in Firefox and Chrome but works in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code which simulates a dropdown multi-checkbox

```
<div>
   <div class="select">
       <span>Select something</span>
   </div>
   <div class="no-display select-list">
       <div>
          <label class="unchecked" for="value1">
             Value1
          </label>
          <label class="unchecked" for="value2">
             Value2
          </label>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And javascript:

```
  $(".select").live("click", function () {
     $(".select-list").toggleClass("no-display").focus();
  });

  $(".select-list").live("blur", function () {
     $(this).addClass("no-display");
  });
```

But in Firefox and Chrome, the blur event doesn't work, but works in IE9.

I want, when clicking outside `select-list` element, to close it (means make it invisible).

I used `blur` event after assigned `focus` on that element.

Could you show me the good approach to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: just a side note: `live` is obsolete, `on` is the new daddy :P

Comment: I tried both `live` and `on`. Same problem.

Comment: The "blur" event does not bubble, and hence it cannot be used in a delegate handler.  It works in IE9 probably because jQuery explicitly works to "fix" event bubbling, and in this case it fixes it a little too much.

Comment: Who is .localization-list I don't think you have that in your snippets? Perhaps, creating a http://jsfiddle.net that highlights your problem might help and draw attention to your question.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. `.localization-list` was replaced with `.select-list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try trapping a click on the document to hide the menu. The clicks from the menu will also propagate to the document so you'll need a work around for that (you can check event.originalEvent for example).

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/FKhhN/2/)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Your script, in my project, open and make `select-list` invisible so the click event has no effect. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `on("focusout",` instead of `on("blur"),`, because the `blur` event doesn't always get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Set attribute `tabindex=-1` on the select-list div(read about "tabindex" property).